# Error in using custom wsdl with axis2

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I am writing a webservice in java, in order to deploy it in *axis2.war*, but I don't want axis2 to automatically generate the wsdl, I have written my own custom wsdl file that I want axis2 to use.
So when I am creating the *.aar* file to deploy it in axis2, in *services.xml*, I added the following tag:

```
<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
```

and then I added the wsdl file that I want axis2 to use in the META-INF folder under the name *service.xml*, then I placed my *.aar* file under *axis2.war/WEB-INF/services*.

Then I configured jetty to use the *axis2.war* file that I created.

The problem is that *axis2.war* is not using my wsdl file and instead when I get the following error from axis2:

```
<error>
<description>Unable to generate WSDL 1.1 for this service</description>
<reason> If you wish Axis2 to automatically generate the WSDL 1.1, then please set useOriginalwsdl as false in your services.xml</reason>
</error>
```

I tried with versions 1.6.2 and with 1.5.4 of axis2 and it didn't work. I tried to search for another way to do it and also didn't find anything.

Is there something I am missing when creating the *.aar* file or when creating the *axis2.war*? Anyone has had this problem and knows a work-around? Or another way to use my custom wsdl file instead of the automatically generated one by axis2?

Comment: Perhaps the WSDL that you're putting in the AAR has the wrong name. See the linked question.

Comment: no actually I tried that, but still got the same result... according to axis2 documentation the wsdl file can be named either service.xml, or (yourServiceName).xml